# Creating an API Layer on top of Firebase Real-Time Database

Tags: rest, api, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, aws-lambda

I do have some data stored in my Real-Time Firebase database. I am willing to expose some of this data via a REST API to my B2B customers.

I know that Firebase is itself a REST API but its authentication mechanisms don't fit my needs. I am willing my customers to access the API with a simple API Key passed in the HTTP request headers.

To summarize, I need an API layer sitting on top of my Firebase real-time database with the following properties:

- Basic Authentication via an API key passed in the HTTP request headers
- Some custom logic that makes sure customers respect the API limits (maximum requests per day for example)

The only thing I can think of is implementing this layer in AWS lambda but that also sounds a bit off. From the lambda, I would have to access my Firebase database and serve that data. That seems too many network requests; something native to Firebase would be great.

Thanks,
Guven.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After some research, I have decided that AWS is the best platform such API related features.

- Gateway API lets you setup your API interface in a matter of seconds
- DynamoDB stores your API data; you can easily populate the data here
- AWS Lambda lets you write the integration code between Gateway API and DynamoDB

On top of these, the platform offers these features out of the box:

- Creation & handling and verification of API keys for authentication
- Usage plans to make sure that API consumers don't exceed your API usage limits

Most of what I was looking for is offered in these AWS services.

Answer (score 3):

Why not have a simple API which provides them an Oauth token for the  original firebase REST API if they have the correct Api Key

It'll be more secure as only you'll be able to make the tokens as only you'll have the service account private key. Also saves you the headache of making a whole REST API. Also the Oauth tokens expire relatively quickly so it's less of a risk than a normal key that you furnish

I personally have created my own Servlets where a user posts their data if they are authenticated using an id pass combo.

In the Servlets i use the default REST API provided by Firebase with the Oauth generated in my servlet. This way, i can have the DB security rules set to false for all writes from any client api. And the REST API and their admin sdk on my server ignore the security rules by default.